# How to upload a file to ftp server in azure from .net MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, ftp

I want to upload my images to my ftp server which is in azure.

How can I do that?

Comment: I mean programmatically.

Comment: there's no upload with FTP. You can store the file in Local Storage or Blob Storage (recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Upload to Local Storage:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/windows-azure-local-storage-feature/

Upload to a Blob Storage (recommended)

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/